# Swift xcode error: Value of type 'DetailViewController' has no member 'Animal'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to make a swift project with a list of animals, then when you click on one of the rows, you get transported to another window where it tells you the description of the animal.

[image]

Here is the code if the screenshot is too small:

```
import UIKit
class AnimalListTableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
        sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController, let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            detailViewController.Animal = animals[indexPath.row] //this is where I get the error that says "Value of type 'DetailViewController' has no member 'Animal"
        }
    }
}
```

Code of DetailViewController class:

```
import UIKit


class DetailViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    var animal: Animal?
    var a = Animal?()


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        titleLabel.text = a!.name
        descriptionLabel.text = a!.longDescription
    }



    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

ListOfAnimals class code:

```
import Foundation


let animals = [
    ListOfAnimals(name: "Cow",
        shortDescription: "Cattle",
        longDescription: "A cow is a mature female and bull of an adult male of a bovine family. A heifer is a female cow that hasn't had a calf yet. Cattle is the name for the whole cow family. THere are about 920 different breeds of cows in the world."),

    ListOfAnimals(name: "Bird",
        shortDescription: "Usually small, has wings, feathers, and can fly.",
        longDescription: "A warm-blooded egg-laying vertebrate distinguished by the possession of feathers, wings, and a beak and (typically) by being able to fly."),

    ListOfAnimals(name: "Dolphin",
        shortDescription: "A large fish",
        longDescription: "A small gregarious toothed whale that typically has a beaklike snout and a curved fin on the back. Dolphins have become well known for their sociable nature and high intelligence."),

    ListOfAnimals(name: "Dog",
        shortDescription: "Man's best friend",
        longDescription: "A domesticated carnivorous mammal that typically has a long snout, an acute sense of smell, and a barking, howling, or whining voice. It is widely kept as a pet or for work or field sports."),

    ListOfAnimals(name: "Zebra",
        shortDescription: "A horse with white and black stripes",
        longDescription: "an African wild horse with black-and-white stripes and an erect mane."),

]

class ListOfAnimals
{


    var name: String
    //var type: Type
    var shortDescription: String
    var longDescription: String

    init(name: String, shortDescription: String, longDescription: String)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.shortDescription = shortDescription
        self.longDescription = longDescription
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
detailViewController.animal
```

Instead of:

```
detailViewController.Animal
```

Comment: that worked but now I'm getting a follow up error that underlines the "animals[indexPath.row]" and the error says "Cannot subscript a value of type '[ListOfAnimals]'

Comment: If it worked then please accept the answer and create a new question describing the new issue you're having and provide more info.